# partial text in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<a class="ui-autocomplete-row ui-corner-all"
    aria-label="(1100)Texas (PL1200/PC1030)- (200167)-Supplies: Other Supplies (620038): 1100-1200-200167-620038" 
    id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1">
    (1100)- (PL1200/PC1030)-(200167)-Supplies: 
    Other Supplies (620038):
    <u><b>1100-1200-200167-620038</b></u>
</a>
```

In Xpath, I want to check if `aria-label` contains the value "1100-1200-200167-620038". It looks like there is a syntax error in the below statement:

```py
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@aria-label="1100-1200-200164-620038"]')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two option like this:

1. CSS Selector

```
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[aria-label*="1100-1200-200167-620038"]')))
```

2. Xpath:

```
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@aria-label, "1100-1200-200167-620038")]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath can be a hassle sometimes, I recommend using the CSS selector method to accomplish this:

```py
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-label='1100-1200-200167-620038']")
```

You could them use the element in your `visibility_of_element_located` method.